# CSS conent is jumping on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have this website: [CLICK](http://fotokluczniok.pl/). And there is `a.nav-toggle`. Viewed on pc it loooks normally in center but when i visit that page on my mobile phone i jumps up. 
css:

```
    .nav-toggle{
        position: absolute;
        right: -50px;
        top: 0;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background: #404040;
        line-height: 45px;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
        /* border-bottom-right-radius: 3px; */
        box-shadow: 1px 0 3px #404040;
        outline: 0;
    }
    .nav-toggle:before {
        content: "\2192";
        font-weight: 600;
        color: white;
        display: inline-block;
    }

   .nav-side.nav-open .nav-toggle:before{
        content: "\2190";
   }
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

Was unable to replicate issue using device-toolbar function in dev tools for Chrome however, I'm assuming you mean when the search bar (at the top of the mobile screen header) closes for mobile devices when you scroll the web page, this is affecting your nav-bar.

If you add

`overflow: hidden;`

to css class `.nav-open`, not `.nav-toggle` this will fix the random behaviour when you scroll the page.